# How to calculate "in between results" based upon given reference list with additional serial number identification?

Tags: excel, mapping, formula, interpolation, vlookup

For (almost) each technical visit there is a record: 
SERVICE DATE / MACHINE #SN / HOURS OF OPERATION 
in Table A (all machines in the same list).

All installed spare parts are recorded with
DATE INSTALLED / MACHINE #SN / ARTIKEL CODE
in Table B

I want to interpolate the according HOURS OF OPERATION for each spare part installed utilizing #SN and DATE as identifier. I have no idea how to isolate just the "SERVICE HOUR RECORDS" with the according #SN in order to perform the needed interpolation.

[DROPBOX LINK TO DEMO XLS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4z47f91wxoa99n/Example%20File.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting a match for each... is that expected? Try out the below.

J7: (Enter With Ctrl+Shift+Enter) =INDEX($E$7:$E$36,MATCH(G7&H7,$C$7:$C$36&$D$7:$D$36,0))